# Performance considerations with setOnClickListener(this)

Tags: java, android

In Android/Java, if I have a button, I can add a click listener two ways -

1)

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.my_button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

     }
});
```

-- or --

2)

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.my_button);
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

I sometimes prefer option #2, mainly because of brevity, but am curious about the performance considerations of essentially passing the entire class/context to the Listener...

Does anyone have any thoughts/experience in regards to this ?

Comment: This has already been answered pretty efficiently here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/110106/what-is-the-proper-way-to-implement-the-onclicklistener-interface-for-many-butto

Comment: thanks, that's a helpful link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter approach is obviously more efficient: All it does is passing a reference to `this`, an already existing object, to `setOnClickListener`, which will then be used to call `onClick`.

The first approach is slightly less efficient as it creates a new object, an instance of an anonymous inner class. The creation of a new object and the existence of an additional class is the main difference.

You might also produce some overhead using the first approach when dealing with variable transactions between the surrounding class and the anonymous inner class. Most issues, e.g. threading related problems, affect both approaches.

Summing up, there is no real performance difference. If you are going to create a lot of buttons, you should consider sharing a single instance of a `View.OnClickListener`.

I usually prefer anonymous inner classes (up to a limited size), because it separates the code that actually belongs to the surrounding class from the code related to the listener.

The actual contents of your listener implementation will affect the performance way more than the call to `setOnClickListener`. From the perspective of `setOnClickListener`, both calls are equal as they both pass an instance of a class implementing `View.OnClickListener`, whether reused or created.

Comment: good points, and helpful answer... (not going to accept as I think this is more of an opinion piece, but did upvote... ) ... appreciate your response.

Comment: @jesses.co.tt My answer is not really based on opinions. The only part that's not entirely based on facts is the second to last paragraph. If your question was meant to attract opiniated answers, you did not understand the concept of stackoverflow, which explicitely rejects opinions.

Answer (score 2):

I think both methods are valid

All depends on what you want to do. For example, if you have many buttons on a screen and you choose to use the first option, for each button you'll need a new object to handle the click. In contrast to the second option, with the same object (activity) as a listener, you'll consume fewer resources because it would be creating fewer objects (Java).

On the other hand, remember that the view holds a reference to context.

Comment: good points, and helpful answer... (not going to accept as I think this is more of an opinion piece, but did upvote... ) ... appreciate your response.